# Using sum in Oracle SQL view to add column total in each row

Tags: oracle, view, sum

i have a simple Oracle View with 3 columns team, minors, adults as follows:-

```
 create view main_summary ( team, minors, adults)
  as 
     select all_teams.team_name as team , 
     case when age<18 then count(id) as minors,
     case when age>= 18 then count(id) as adults
     from all_teams ;
```

a select statement return rows like:-

```
    -----------------------------
       team   |   minors  | adults
     -----------------------------
      volleyball    2        4
      football      6        3
       tennis       4        8
    -------------------------------
```

i want to add a total column in the end which should make the view look like:-

```
    --------------------------------------
       team      | minors | adults| total
    --------------------------------------
      volleyball    2        4       6
      football      6        3       9
      tennis        4        8       12  
    -----------------------------------------
```

i tried following, but nothing worked:-

```
    create view main_summary( team, minors, adults, sum(minors+adults)) ...
     and
     create view main_summary ( team, minors, adults, total)
  as 
     select all_teams.team_name as team , 
     case when age<18 then count(id) as minors,
     case when age>= 18 then count(id) as adults
     sum (  case when age<18 then count(id) + 
       case when age>= 18 then count(id) ) as total ...
```

The syntax may not be correct as i am not copying directly from my Database. However, pseudo code remains the same. Please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: Your original query should not work in Oracle, and it certainly should not return more than one row.  Even if you add in the `GROUP BY team_name`, it should still normally fail in Oracle.

Comment: interestingly, my original query works. the syntax i put in here may be little wrong as i m away from my server. i will share my original query in 24 hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why your original view works.  I think you want:

```
create view main_summary as 
     select t.team_name as team , 
            sum(case when age < 18 then 1 else 0 end) as minors,
            sum(case when age >= 18 then 1 else 0 end) as adults,
            count(*) as total
     from all_teams
     group by t.team_name;
```

Comment: what if i need total of only two result columns and not the third. eg. if there are cats like age<18 = minors, age>18<25 adults, age > 25 matures and i just want total to be that of over 18 then count(*) wont suffice????

Comment: @jaykio77 . . . Then you need the `case` expression.